# targeting to execute docker-compose without sudo command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I don't have issue running docker without sudo. But when I execute docker-compose without sudo, I get this error message. Everything works perfect when running with sudo. I installed docker-compose from "pip install". My question is: How to run docker-compose without sudo?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/docker-compose",
>   line 7, in 
>       from compose.cli.main import main ImportError: No module named compose.cli.main

Your help is much appreciated...

Comment: Probably some path differences in the environment. Check outputs of `env` and `sudo env`, see if you can spot differences

Comment: there are a few docker-compose from bin pathes... i just made them chmod 755 and it works now ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason is that any file that is used by docker-compose is not owned by the current user. We can change this by using this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER .
```